# how to set json data in table view

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I want to get data from Json and put it in the table and display it from the API via Alamofire through the 'Post' process that has parameters containing the page number

I want get "results" ..

{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "message": null,
    "status": true,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 971,
            "title": "ST201972362",
            "cdate": "07/31/2019",
            "summary": "test",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "77876203",
            "lat": "31.515934",
            "lng": "34.4494066",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-31T13:38:46.927",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 970,
            "title": "ST201972356",
            "cdate": "07/30/2019",
            "summary": "ov",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "31.5159315",
            "lng": "34.4493925",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-30T15:26:00.077",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 964,
            "title": "ST201972341",
            "cdate": "07/29/2019",
            "summary": "تجربة بلاغ ",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "21.5066086",
            "lng": "39.1758587",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-29T19:06:58.817",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 959,
            "title": "ST201972820252314",
            "cdate": "07/28/2019",
            "summary": "اااااا",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "21.5066716",
            "lng": "39.1758483",
            "source": "1",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-28T11:45:02.493",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 957,
            "title": "ST201972312",
            "cdate": "07/28/2019",
            "summary": "تمتمتم",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "31.5397884",
            "lng": "34.4544891",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-28T08:56:43.577",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 956,
            "title": "ST201972312",
            "cdate": "07/28/2019",
            "summary": "لا تنام",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "31.5397238",
            "lng": "34.4540829",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-28T08:56:00.15",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 955,
            "title": "ST201972311",
            "cdate": "07/28/2019",
            "summary": "تجربه جديد",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "31.5395001",
            "lng": "34.4542211",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-28T08:52:09.81",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 953,
            "title": "ST201972309",
            "cdate": "07/28/2019",
            "summary": "يلا",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "31.5110196",
            "lng": "34.4784933",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-28T05:30:29.647",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 952,
            "title": "ST201972309",
            "cdate": "07/28/2019",
            "summary": "ماك ١",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "31.5110291",
            "lng": "34.4785841",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-28T05:29:09.943",
            "done_940": null
        },
        {
            "id": 949,
            "title": "ST201972307",
            "cdate": "07/28/2019",
            "summary": "مرحبا",
            "address": "",
            "timer": "0",
            "lat": "31.5443154",
            "lng": "34.4585304",
            "source": "2",
            "CreatedOn": "2019-07-28T00:20:42.753",
            "done_940": null
        }
    ],
    "done_940": "2/811"
}

Comment: use this link to get the codable struct model and then parse the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow some steps:

Step 1: need to create model

```
 struct ResultObject {
    var responseCode: Int?
    var message: String?
    var status: Bool?
    var result: [Result]

    public init(response: [String: Any]) {
        self.responseCode = response["responseCode"] as? Int
        self.message = response["message"] as? String
        self.status = response["status"] as? Bool
        let results = response["result"] as! [[String: Any]]
        self.result = []
        for item in results {
           let result = Result(result: item)
            self.result.append(result)
        }
    }

    struct Result {
        var id: String?
        var title: String?
        var cdate: String?
        var summary: String?
        var address: String?
        var timer: String?
        var lat: String?
        var lng: String?
        var source: String?
        var CreatedOn: String?
        var done_940: String?

        public init(result: [String: Any]) {
            self.id = result["id"] as? String
            self.title = result["title"] as? String
            self.cdate = result["cdate"] as? String
            self.summary = result["summary"] as? String
            self.address = result["address"] as? String
            self.timer = result["timer"] as? String
            self.lat = result["lat"] as? String
            self.lng = result["lng"] as? String
            self.source = result["source"] as? String
            self.CreatedOn = result["CreatedOn"] as? String
            self.done_940 = result["done_940"] as? String
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: You check response from Alamofile
if you get json then

```
let test = ResultObject(response: responseJson)
print(test)
```

incase you get response is type Response you must convert into json

```
let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: [])
if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
    let test = ResultObject(response: responseJSON)
    print(test)
}
```

Let me know when you have some other problems.

Comment: thanks , that's right :)

Comment: But I want to link some data from the Json file like the title and address in the table view